# MySQL only imports half of the database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

My server is run with a VestaCP admin panel.

I have a 4.7 gb database. I exported it from phpMyadmin and it became 1 gb .sql file. I realised after backing up the database on my new server that it was not the full database.

I then did a mysql dump to a temporary folder and backed it up to the new server again. This file is around 2.5 gb but when imported it was not the full database. It only uploaded 1 gb and half the tables are missing. I did not get an error when importing it from the command line.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong or how I can import a large database?

Comment: I would highly recommend using MySQL Workbench instead of phpMyAdmin. It is significantly more reliable/capable when it comes to imports and exports.

Comment: Does the versions of MySQL servers are the same? Does SQL modes, charset/collation and another settings are the same? *and half the tables are missing* You must find the errors in the logfiles and investigate them.

Comment: I would use the command line client; for an export that large you're very likely going to run in to PHP and webserver resource limits (timeouts, memory limit, etc). Using `mysqldump` works around those limitations.